# extract last row of each shift(day& night) from dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi i want to extract last row for **each Shift(day & night)** from dataframe.**sample of the dataframe** is given below.

```
Shift   Mark    value name
Night   34      122    mark
Night   14      1224   gomes
Night   24      1212   nick
Day     34      34     jonas
Day     34      12     ricky
Day     34      0      nick
Night   34      13     ricky
Night   34      12     gomes
Night   34      1200   martin
Day     24      34     jonas
Day     64      12     ricky
Day     664     1      Hayden
```

The expected output is given below:

```
Shift   Mark    value name
Night   24      1212   nick
Day     34      0      nick
Night   34      1200   martin
Day     664     1      Hayden
```

I tried using group by but didn't able to get desired output. What I **want to do is just considering the Shift column, when the Shift changes(Night to day or Day to night), get the last row for each shift.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal like `!=` and test if match shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), last test in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Shift'].ne(df['Shift'].shift(-1))]
print (df)
    Shift  Mark  value    name
2   Night    24   1212    nick
5     Day    34      0    nick
8   Night    34   1200  martin
11    Day   664      1  Hayden
```